# renaming directories based on a pattern

Tags: unix, directory, find

I'm currently trying to rename all directories containing *123* to *321*.
For example, if I have a directory called test123test, I would like to rename it to test321test.
So far, I have something which would look like:
 `find . -depth -name *123* -exec mv {}` **that's where I'm having a problem**`\;`
Because I don't see how I would be able to replace the folder's name based on the original one.
If you have any idea on how to proceed, feel free to contribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with a for loop:

```
for dir in `find . -type d -depth X -name '*123*'` ; do
    mv "$dir" "${dir/123/321}"
done
```

*Note:* you need to edit `X` in the above. And it might fail if there are paths like '`./dir123/dir123/`'

Comment: Thanks a bunch, it worked after I removed the depth predicate.